# getaddrinfo: command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, monit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I fix “getaddrinfo: localhost Name or service not found” for telnet server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/129556/how-do-i-fix-getaddrinfo-localhost-name-or-service-not-found-for-telnet-serve)

I've installed a new Ubuntu 12.04 on an AWS EC2 instance and everything worked fine till now. I followed the instructions in this great tutorial: http://www.exratione.com/2012/05/a-mailserver-on-ubuntu-1204-postfix-dovecot-mysql/

Now i'm on the point "installing monit" and when i restart the service i get this error message now:

```
monit: Cannot translate '(none)' to FQDN name -- Name or service not known
```

I started googling and someone is writing there, that monit uses getaddrinfo in his startup-process to determine the hostname. Ok, so i thought i try out on myself what is getaddrinfo delivering, and then i got:

```
getaddrinfo: command not found
```

I guess, something is missing on my system. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

`getaddrinfo` is a library function in the standard C library, not a command line tool. So trying to execute it is not quite the right path to a solution. You *can* call getaddrinfo from a python shell if you want:

```
dennis@lightning:~$ python
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getaddrinfo('localhost', None)
[(2, 1, 6, '', ('127.0.0.1', 0)), (2, 2, 17, '', ('127.0.0.1', 0)), (2, 3, 0, '', ('127.0.0.1', 0))]
```

but I doubt that this will help you solve your problem. Instead, follow the link in Michael's comment.

Comment: I was coming across this while searching for a getaddrinfo command line tool. Didn’t find any and use now `python -c 'import socket; print(socket.getaddrinfo("www.domain.com", "ssh")[0][4][0])'` for example

Answer (score 0):

[How do I fix "getaddrinfo: localhost Name or service not found" for telnet server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/129556/how-do-i-fix-getaddrinfo-localhost-name-or-service-not-found-for-telnet-serve)

I think this should help you. Had same problem and this is exactly what caused it (having some scripts as well which automatically set some DNS stuff).